# Using Camunda REST API, can I create a batch to update multiple distinct instances variables?

Tags: camunda

My question is if there is any Camunda REST API endpoint to update multiple Process Instances variables at once. For example:

/POST engine-rest/batch

```json
{
  "updates": [
    {"processInstanceId": "instance1", "variables": {"someVar": "value1"} },
    {"processInstanceId": "instance2", "variables": {"someVar": "value2"} },
    {"processInstanceId": "instance3", "variables": {"someOtherVar": "value1"} },
  ],
}
```

I searched on Camunda REST API documentation but I think they only provide this
POST /process-instance/{id}/variables

But I need to update many instances at once. Is there any endpoint for that?

Thank you all